# Convert object's key to string

Tags: javascript, json

I got following `json` from services:

```
{Key1 : "val1", Key2 : "val2"}
```

I need to convery `Key1` to the `"Key1"` and `Key2` to the `"Key2"`, because i want to `JSON.stringify` this object, but it gives error when keys not strings.

How to convert object's keys to string?

**UPD** Yes, sorry, `{Key1 : "val1", Key2 : "val2"}` works, but i have sometimes keys with `-` symbol, like `{Key-1 : "val1"}` and got `Unexpected token` in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/aXeMoZE/1/edit?html,js,output What browser are you using?

Comment: How do you generate your json object ? An index with the '-' char without quote is illegal.

Comment: How are you creating the object? It works fine for me in chrome like this - http://jsfiddle.net/4M2X8/1/

Comment: As long as your JS engine accepts the JSON (hence "valid"), `JSON.stringify` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mentioned your own problem the `-` is not allowed unless it's quoted, so you should use 'key-1' in that case

Answer (score 1):

You should report a bug to your service provider, since the response is not [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/). This should be a easy bug to fix.

If this is not possible, you could write a Javascript method to add quotes to all *key* s in the response. This could be a nightmare since the *key* could be any character (`-` , `:` , `;` , `}` ...)